# Configure Puppeteer executablePath chrome in your local Windows

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

- Puppeteer version : 1.11.0
- Platform / OS version: Windows 10 pro
- Node.js version: 12.6.6

When I did a local development  test in windows, happen was problem in executablePath.

"Failed to launch chrome! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT"

I saw for windows needs to get complete path. Otherwise cannot find chrome.exe

Default in code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/path/to/Chrome'});
```

In windows it worked thus:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\your_workspace\\node_modules\\puppeteer\\.local-chromium\\win64-(version)\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe'});
```

In visual code suggest the path

[Visual Code view explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocS1k.png)

Comment: I confirm that's solution worked correctly in my case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
const osPlatform = os.platform(); // possible values are: 'darwin', 'freebsd', 'linux', 'sunos' or 'win32'
console.log('Scraper running on platform: ', osPlatform);
let executablePath;
if (/^win/i.test(osPlatform)) {
  executablePath = '';
} else if (/^linux/i.test(osPlatform)) {
  executablePath = '/usr/bin/google-chrome';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also set the environment variable `PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH`.

This is useful in conjunction with `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` set to `true`

Comment: thank you for this env tip i can use now chrome as background browser :D